# VBA Debug.Print semi colon

Tags: vba

What is the actual value/meaning of a semi colon ( **;** ) with the `Debug.Print` statement in VBA?

I use this often but have no real understanding of it, all I know is that it isn't equal to the `vbTab` constant as the spacing isn't the same.

i.e.

```
Debug.Print 123;456;789
Debug.Print 123 & vbTab & 456 & vbTab & 789
```

produce different outputs.

Comment: This just became my new favorite [undocumented feature](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg264286.aspx).

Comment: @RubberDuck just had a read of that article, but I think it raised more questions than answers!

Comment: Agreed! I'd like to see an answer with a documentation reference.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It suppresses the generation of a newline character sequence which would otherwise cause a subsequent call to `Debug.Print` to output on the next line.

(In your case it's redundant: you'd see an explicit effect if you adjust your first line to `Debug.Print 123;456;789;`)

Comment: Both answers gave me what I needed to know but this was a very good explanation so I marked this one as the answer :)

Answer (score 5):

A `;` at the end of a Print statement suppresses the usual default `CRLF`.